# Add items to ListView from another xml file

Tags: android, listview

hey guys I have a ListView in "main" with DataTimePickerDialog.class and i want from this class to add an Items to the ListView in  "activity_notification" with notification.class , this is a picture to main.xml and my code : please help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhpo.png)

```
public class DateTimePickerDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener, DateTimePickerDialog.DateTimeListener {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.ButtonTime).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view.getId() == R.id.ButtonTime)
        showDateTimeDialog();

}

private void showDateTimeDialog() {
    DateTimePickerDialog pickerDialog = new DateTimePickerDialog(this, false, this);
    pickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onDateTimeSelected(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int am_pm) {
    String text = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " - " + hour + ":" + min;
    if (am_pm != -1)
        text = text + (am_pm == Calendar.AM ? "AM" : "PM");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Date)).setText(text);
}
```

Comment: You can pass the data from one activity to anther activity by using bundle

Comment: the problem I'm new in android , please ken you give me an exemple